# React Router, change path alternative of link element

Tags: hyperlink, path, react-router

Is it possible to change route in react by react-router by other way than `<Link></Link>` ?
(e.g change route when onClick, or onKeydown event runs some function)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. You can use history.push in your code:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return <button onClick={() => history.push('/profile')}>Profile</button>;
};
```